# Html/CSS: Show Text in Diagonally Split Rectangle

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Using HTML/CSS I would like to show the diagonal of an imaginary rectangle and write some text above and below.

The ultimate goal is to write a heading for a kind of table in the upper left corner, describing the row-headers and the column-headers.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could try to look at SVG? It allows you to draw polygons and have a text field inside the polygon. Or perhaps CSS Clip path? https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: Thank you, good idea, I tried that, but had major issues with dimensions, relativ sizes...

Comment: You can use CSS shape-outside to get the text nicely inserted in each triangular shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That is possible in pure html/css!**

Here some code ... colors are for demonstration. Code is based on a `<div>` container. But it should work on a `<th>`/`<td>` as well. Adapt code to your needs.

**HEAD UP**: you need to have a look to the dimensions (width, height of the heading boxes, sizing of outer box, font size of heading ...) on different responsive views AND different devices as fonts may be displayed slightly different wide ... and could break your layout.

```css
.dbox {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
/* add diagonal line */
.dbox:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, transparent calc(50% - 1px), green, transparent calc(50% + 1px)  );

}
/* align boxes with headings */
.dheading_tr,
.dheading_bl{
    position: absolute;
    /* or wider if needed/possible */
    width: 50%; 
    height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
} 
.dheading_tr {  
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.dheading_bl {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="dbox">

    <div class="dheading_tr">Top right</div>
    <div class="dheading_bl">Bottom left</div>

</div>
```